# get the last thursday todate in android

Tags: android, date, datetime

Hi everybody hope your all ok, 
Got a problem that I am total stuck on, if you've got any ideas that can help?

In my app I can get current date and time as below. But what I need is the date of the last Thursday just gone, but not sure how to do this?

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy-HH:mm");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
String start = "Last Thursday was: ";
String date = (dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
String all = (start + date);
```

Thanks in advance for any advice.
T.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

not android specific but in general if

- R is today's date
- Rd is today's (R) day number of the week
- X is day number of week (5 for thursday -- or is it 4?)
- L is the max day number (7 or 6 depending on indexing)

Then last thursday (not including today if today is thursday) is:

```
R - (Rd - X + L)days
```

I don't speak this language but based upon the other answers this seems like the code.  Short and sweet. please edit if not correct.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); //today 
cal.add (Calendar.DATE,
            -( cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - Calendar.THURSDAY + Calendar.SATURDAY )
         );
```

Comment: I thought about this for a while and I think that `R - Rd + X - L days` would be easier to understand. Also, instead of 5 you could use the constant `Calendar.THURSDAY`.

Comment: WOW thank you that worked great, don't quite understand, but will keep looking at it. If today is Thursday then just check and switch to either one

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
long startTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
cal.set (Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.THURSDAY); // may move forwards or backwards
if (cal.getTimeInMillis() > startTime)  // we went forwards, so
   cal.add (Calendar.DATE, -7);         // go back one week.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

while (cal.get( Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK ) != Calendar.THURSDAY)
        {
        cal.add( Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -1 );
        }

Date lastThursday = cal.getTime();
```

The `Date` object `lastThursday` will represent the current time of day, but the most recent thursday in the past. You can then format the `Date` as you do above with the current time.

If you do not need the hours and minutes in your `String` then change the `SimpleDateFormatter` to be:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

The solution above includes the possibility of today being the most recent Thursday. If you do not want to include today then make this a `do-while` loop instead:

```
  do
      {
      cal.add( Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -1 );
      }
  while (cal.get( Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK ) != Calendar.THURSDAY);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method

```
public static String getLastThursday(){
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add (Calendar.DATE, -( cal.get( Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK ) -5 + 7 ) );

    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

    String lastThursday = df.format(cal.getTime());
    return lastThursday;
}
```

Which will format a string with last thursdays date. You can modify df to format the date string as you like [see here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Credits to @gillyspy for very elegant one line date adjust!